# LineChartView (danielgindi/charts) line disappears when zoom in or drag

Tags: ios, swift, line, ios-charts

LineChartView (danielgindi/charts) line disappears when zoom in or drag.

[image: If you click you can see GIF file.]

```
var bChartView: LineChartView = {
     let lcv = LineChartView()
     lcv.backgroundColor = .white
     lcv.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
     lcv.xAxis.setLabelCount(5, force: true)
     lcv.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
     lcv.leftAxis.inverted = true
     lcv.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
     lcv.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
     lcv.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
     lcv.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
     lcv.pinchZoomEnabled = true
     lcv.scaleYEnabled = false
     lcv.scaleXEnabled = true
     lcv.autoScaleMinMaxEnabled = true
     lcv.dragEnabled = true
     lcv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     lcv.legend.enabled = true
     return lcv
}()
```

The chart should not be erased.